# XSLT - Find number range in elements

Tags: xml, xslt

My Input XML is,

```
<link idref="r164">2004</link>
```

Output should be,

```
<link idref="r164" target="literature">2004</link>
```

The conditions are attribute "idref" value should be start with "r" and the link elements contain only 4 digit then we should add the attribute "target="literature"".

Could you please guide us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a template as below.

```
<xsl:template match="link">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="starts-with(@idref, 'r') and string-length(.) = 4">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:attribute name="target">
                <xsl:value-of select="'literature'" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanku for your quick response Ankit.